# Android: Activity is not destroyed using the command 'finishActivity(999)'

Tags: android, android-activity

My currently running activity B should be destroyed using 'finishActivity(999)'. Doing so, I want to get back to the method 'onActivityResult' in activity A which called activity B.
This somehow doesn't work. Below some code snippets:

```
public class ActivityB extends Activity {
  ...

  // Method listening OnClick event
  public void verifyPassword(View view) {
  ...
  // call http server in order to verify password
  if (httpResponse != 200) {
    finishActivity(999);
  }
  command Z;
}
```

I can see that in the debugger that the finishActivity(999) statement is performed, but after that, simply the next instruction 'command Z' in the same activiy is executed.

Why does the finishActivity(999) statement has no effect?

Comment: Are your request codes the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`finishActivity()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#finishActivity%28int%29) doesn't finish the current activity:

> Force finish another activity that you had previously started with
>   startActivityForResult(Intent, int).

Note *another activity*, not *this activity* (e.g. you could call it from activity a).

You want just [`finish()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#finish%28%29) instead, most likely in combination with [`setResult()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#setResult%28int%29).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I changed the code within the brackets to "setResult(999); finish();". But this leads to the same behaviour, the finish() statments gets somehow ignored.

Comment: Oh yeah, it's been a while. You can return from the method after that and it should be fine (just add `return;` after the finish() call). No other code will be executed inside verifyPassword().

Comment: alextsc, you're the man! This silly return statement after the finish stsatement solved the issue, perfect. Thanks.